# Ruby - Rescue any error related to File or Directory handling?

Tags: ruby

I just want to know if there's some way to rescue from any error related to File or Directory handling.

For example, when someone creates a directory with an invalid name such as `////` or the error when writing or reading a file, etc. I mean, any error related to Files and Directories.

Comment: you can handle it as youd handle any other exepction with  a `begin` `rescue` `end` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html

Comment: Yea I know, I'm asking the specific way to do it.

Comment: what do you mean specific way to do it...just wrap your method that handles directory creation with the block and if any exception is raised you can handle it however you want

Comment: I mean what are the specific exceptions, for example `ZeroDivisionError` is for zero division, `NoMemoryError` is for a fail in memory allocation, etc.

Is there any exception to catch all file/directory management in Ruby?

Comment: This would be an exception subclass `Standard Error` specifically `IOError` -  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IOError.html

Answer (score 0):

This would be an exception subclass `Standard Error` specifically `IOError` for an IO operation error(read etc.) and/or `SystemCallError` in the case of trying to open a non-existing file

`IOError` is raised when a IO operation fails. Read more on it from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IOError.html) also read up on the type of [Exceptions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Exception.html) in ruby

`SystemCallError` - is the base class for all low-level platform-dependent errors. Read more on it in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/SystemCallError.html)